# python: after method - screen loads with everything on it already

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I want these 10 letters to appear one-by-one on the screen every few seconds. For some reason, when I use the "after method", it waits till all the letters are loaded internally and then shows the screen with all the letters already on it. Meaning it will wait 15 seconds and then load the screen with all the letters on it. (I hope I explained that clearly)

Here is my work

```
class Game():

    def __init__(self):

        root = Tk()

        root.geometry("1350x730")

        global tile_frame_column  # the labels that go on the screen of letters
        tile_frame_column = {}

        boardh = [[False for x in range(12)] for y in range(12)]

        tiles_letter = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']

        def drawBoard():
            tile_frame_column_counter=0
            for x in range(8):
                for y in range(8):

                    if not tiles_letter:
                        return
                    if not boardh[y][x]:
                        rand = random.choice(tiles_letter)
                        tile_frame_column[tile_frame_column_counter] = Label(root, text=rand, font="Helvetica 16 bold")
                        tile_frame_column[tile_frame_column_counter].place(x=(x)*64+5, y= (y)*64)
                        tile_frame_column_counter+=1
                        tiles_letter.remove(rand)
                        root.after(10000, drawBoard)
        root.after(10000, drawBoard)
        root.mainloop()

app=Game()
```

I've been stuck on this for a while. Hope someone can help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so kevin got you partway, but the issue of all the letters loading simultaneously is not due to the use of the `after` function, it is due to one run-through of `drawBoard` generating all the letters, you have to change the `for` statements to `in range(1)` like this:

```
            for x in range(1):
                for y in range(1):
```

This makes 1 letter at a time, but they are placed in the same position (i.e. on top of each other).

To solve this I suggest you change your approach a bit. Create two variables (for the x and y cordinates) which are added to every time that `drawBoard` is run. here is a full e.g.

```
from tkinter import *
import random

class Game():
    def __init__(self):
        root = Tk()
        root.geometry("1350x730")

        global tile_frame_column  # the labels that go on the screen of letters
        tile_frame_column = {}

        global tile_frame_column_counter
        global newvar1 # x coordinate
        global newvar2 # y coordinate

        tile_frame_column_counter = 0
        newvar1 = 50
        newvar2 = 50

        tiles_letter = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']

        def drawBoard():
            global tile_frame_column_counter
            global newvar1
            global newvar2
            for x in range(1):
                for y in range(1):
                    if not tiles_letter:
                        return
                    else:
                        rand = random.choice(tiles_letter)
                        tile_frame_column[tile_frame_column_counter] = Label(root, text=rand, font="Helvetica 16 bold")
                        tile_frame_column[tile_frame_column_counter].place(x = newvar1, y = newvar2)
                        tile_frame_column_counter+=1
                        if newvar2 > 300:
                            newvar1 += 50
                            newvar2 = 50 # to start at the next column
                        else:
                            newvar2 += 50
                        tiles_letter.remove(rand)
                        root.after(1000, drawBoard)
        root.after(1000, drawBoard)
        root.mainloop()

app=Game()
```

I think this is something like what you had that after five or so letters, the labels were placed in the next column.

hope this works! if not tell me what else is needed :)

Answer (score 2):

```
root.after(10000, drawBoard())
```

The second argument to `after` is supposed to be a function object. but what you're doing here is saying, "call drawBoard right away, and its return value will be the second argument to `after`". Try it without the parentheses.

```
root.after(10000, drawBoard)
```

(Remember to change the `after` call in both the spots you use it)

---

Additionally, in your `drawBoard` function, `root.after` will get called 8*8 times, so all your subsequent calls will execute simultaneously. If you want `drawBoard` to fill in a single cell, wait X seconds, fill in a single cell, wait X seconds, etc, then you should `return` after you first successfully fill in a cell. Also, you forgot to populate `boardh` with your completed letters.

```
#rest of function goes here...
tile_frame_column[tile_frame_column_counter].place(x=(x)*64+5, y= (y)*64)
tile_frame_column_counter+=1
tiles_letter.remove(rand)
boardh[y][x] = rand
root.after(1000, drawBoard)
return
```

Comment: thanks! but it still loads the letters simultaneously. I will edit the above code though to how you said.  But it is a major improvement though

Comment: now it loads the screen. It stays blank for 15 seconds. After 15 seconds, all letters appears on the screen at once.